# matplotlib pyplot display ticks and values which are in scientific form

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, linegraph

I have a plot which looks like this:

[image]
The values displayed on the blue line are the cost ratio.

The corresponding code looks like this:

```
    fpr=[some values]
    tpr=[some values]
    CR = 
    plt.plot(tpr,fpr)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.plot(*intersection.xy, 'ro')
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.legend(["Cost Ratio"])
    for x,y,z in zip(tpr,fpr,CR):
        label = "{:.2f}".format(z) 
        plt.annotate(label, # this is the text
                     (x,y),annotation_clip=True, # these are the coordinates to position the label
                     textcoords="offset points", # how to position the text
                     xytext=(0,10), # distance from text to points (x,y)
                     ha='center') # horizontal alignment can be left, right or center
    
    
    plt.show()
```

The cost ratio values are :

```
[3.436400227231698e-11
6.872800454463395e-11
1.374560090892679e-10
2.749120181785358e-10
5.498240363570716e-10
1.0996480727141433e-09
2.1992961454282866e-09
4.398592290856573e-09
8.797184581713146e-09
1.7594369163426292e-08
37.7836200753334]
```

I want to display the following values:

```
[3.4e-11
6.8e-11
1.3e-10
2.7e-10
5.4e-10
1.0e-09
2.1e-09
4.3e-09
8.7e-09
1.7e-08
37.7]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `label = "{:.2f}".format(z)`, the `.2f` refers to fixed point notation with two decimals. This gives you `0.00` when your small numbers are presented with two decimals.

For scientific notation with one decimal, you need to use `.1e`, that is `label = "{:.1e}".format(z)`. This will give you the numbers you want to display.

Note that this will not work for `37.7` as the scientific notation with 1 decimal of this number will be `3.8e+01`. You could use an if/else to apply the scientific notation to all the numbers but `37.7`.

The different string format types are found in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).